# Using decodeByteArray to convert bitmap: Showing a black image and LogCat shows skimagedecoder factory returned null

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap

I am trying to receive an image from a remote server which sends images every 5 seconds. Right now, on the Android side, I am using `decodeByteArray()` to convert it to a bitmap. When it is running, sometimes it shows an image on the screen, and sometimes it shows a black screen and the LogCat shows  the `skimagedecoder` factory returning `null`. I don't know what the problem is.

Here is the code I have:

```
public class connection extends AsyncTask {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

        int i = 0;
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("134.129.125.126", 8080);
            input = clientSocket.getInputStream();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (true) {
            data = new byte[2048 * 2048];

            try {
                read = input.read(data, 0, data.length);

                System.out.println("getInputStream()");
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, read);

                System.out.println("deco");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    System.out.println("setImage at less than 500");

                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

**Update** 
Right now, try to receive the size of image from server, and make became right size of byte array. then decodeByteArray(), it become Factory returned Null again. here is my revised code:

```
public class connection extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {

            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket("134.129.125.126", 8080);
                System.out.println("client connect to server");
                input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                System.out.println("getinputstream");
            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // while (true) {
            int totalBytesRead = 0;
            int chunkSize = 0;
            int tempRead = 0;
            String msg = null;
            // byte[] data = null;
            byte[] tempByte = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 4];
            try {
                tempRead = input.read(tempByte);
                System.out.println("read:" + tempRead);

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (tempRead < 2000) {
                String message = new String(tempByte, 0, tempRead);
                msg = message.substring(0, 6);
                System.out.println("message head:" + msg);
                byteSize = Integer.parseInt(msg);
                System.out.println("ByteSize:" + byteSize);
                data = new byte[byteSize];
            }

            try {

                while (chunkSize > -1) {
                    System.out.println("data length:" + data.length);
                    chunkSize = input.read(data, totalBytesRead, data.length
                            - totalBytesRead);
                    System.out.println("chunkSize is " + chunkSize);
                    totalBytesRead += chunkSize;
                    System.out.println("Total byte read " + totalBytesRead);
                    if (totalBytesRead == data.length) {
                        if (input.read() != -1) {
                            // error, the file is larger than our buffer
                            throw new RuntimeException("Buffer overflow error!");
                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

            System.out.println("deco");

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    System.out.println("setImage at less than 500");

                }
            });

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, there is no guarantee that your read command is reading the whole image. InputStreams tend to read the number of bytes currently available, which may or may not be until end of file, that is implementation dependent.

You should continue reading into your byte array until the value returned from `input.read()` is -1. This will obviously require a rework of some of the logic to loop until you get a -1 back and have a variable that tracks total bytes read as the summation of all the read calls.

For example, to read everything out of a stream

```
int totalBytesRead = 0;
int chunkSize = 0;
byte[] fileBuffer = new byte[4 * 1024 * 1024];  // 4MB buffer

while (chunkSize > -1) {
    chunkSize = inputStream.read(fileBuffer, totalBytesRead, fileBuffer.length - totalBytesRead);
    totalBytesRead += chunkSize;
    if (totalBytesRead == fileBuffer.length) {
        if (inputStream.read() != -1) {
            // error, the file is larger than our buffer
            throw new RuntimeException("Buffer overflow error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me some tips or example? I don't know how to make sure to read all of inputstream at a time.

Comment: Is this fileBuffer size should be same as the file I sent from server? because my image's size is dynamic, So Idk it works for me .

Comment: right now, I think the problems is make sure the size of file from server need match the filebuffer in the client side. Do you think I can determine the size of file then sent to the client, and client this this size for Filebuffer? Maybe it is stupid idea, Idk if there is any more smart way?

Comment: It just depends on what the server is doing, I believe content size is an HTTP header you can set. Alternately you can read into a number of smaller chunks which you assemble into a List of chunks and then after everything is read allocate a new array that is the total bytes read and copy each of the chunks into the final array.

Comment: Great, I think I can handle it now. Thanks.

Comment: Could you help me check again, I am using this fine out of while loop, but right now I need get update image every 5 sec. I don't know why I got the same size as server sent, but it is still give me factory returnned null.

Comment: if I am using decodeStream, and do skip the read() method, is it problem with reading whole streaM?